# strange response from spotify api using node js

Tags: node.js, spotify

I am creating  a command line app using nodejs. For some reason whenever I enter a track (node liri.js spotify-this-song "enter track") i get a response of a random band called Nocturnal rites, song named "something undefined", and album called "grand illusion". Does anyone know where I am wrong, or why I am getting these responses?

```
  function spotifyIt(song) {
  spotify.search({ type: 'track', query: song }, function(err, data) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.log('Error occurred: ' + err);
        return;  //from spotify npm docs
    }
    else{
    var songInfo = data.tracks.items[0];
    var songResult = console.log(songInfo.artists[0].name)
                     console.log(songInfo.name)
                     console.log(songInfo.album.name)
                     console.log(songInfo.preview_url)
    console.log(songResult);
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: where did you get that spotify.search ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. had to change the query to the correct params[]... i.e it ended up looking like this

```
function spotifyIt() {
  spotify.search({ type: 'track', query: params[1] }, function(err, data) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.log('Error occurred: ' + err);
        return;  //from spotify npm docs
    }
    else{
    var songInfo = data.tracks.items[0];
    var songResult = console.log(songInfo.artists[0].name)
                     console.log(songInfo.name)
                     console.log(songInfo.album.name)
                     console.log(songInfo.preview_url)
    console.log(songResult);
    };
  });
}
```

I had a global variable `var params = process.argv.slice(2);` and a switch statement with another params[1], so that it ended up calling the fourth parameter i.e. where the song title was named in the terminal

```
switch(params[0]) {
  case "my-tweets":
    myTweets();
    break;
  case "spotify-this-song":
    if(params[1]){  //if a song is put named in 4th paramater go to function
    spotifyIt();
  } else {  //if blank call it blink 182's "whats my age again"
    spotifyIt("What\'s my age again");
  }
    break;
```